# Setting a locale on a group basis

Tags: linux

anyone know if it is possible (and if so, how) to set a specific locale for a user group?

It feels like it should be possible and would have a use in our case, where we have different teams of different nationalities accessing our system, but google throws up no useful links (it may just be the lack of coffee). Anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. As many users from different groups ( some of them share their primary group ) use the same global shell RC file, and each group is identified by user GID - and every user has a GID, then I'd set locale variable LC_* ( LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES etc. ) simply based on $(id -g) of the user reading bashrc/bash_profile file.

```
#group 50 is e.g. staff, so for staff group we want e.g. en_US locale, and so on..
if ( [ `id -g` -eq 50 ] ) ; then export LC_ALL_ ... ; elif .. ; else .. ; fi
```

one may also want to use case/esac syntax.
of course you need to make sure that particular locale is compiled and ready to use, and provide locale "C" as safe failover default.

Comment: new user tip: if you find some answer helpful, you may want to vote it up. Don't worry, you'll gain downvoting privilege when you gather more reputation points :)

Comment: Yes, this would work in our case above, but would require editing all users .bashrc. Thats not really a problem, but I was wondering really if there was some utility/editable file to be able to fix this globally per group, instead of per user.

Comment: Obviously, if you need the behaviour to affect all users in the system, you need editing all users bashrc ( global /etc/bashrc ). It absolutely doesn't mean you need to edit everyone's ~/.bashrc , come on, it's Unix, man :)

Comment: You could also use some PAM_ENV module for that. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module